# why is my solution to Counting valleys problem timing out?

Tags: c#

This is the question to count valleys on HackerRank:

An avid hiker keeps meticulous records of their hikes. During the last hike that took exactly  steps, for every step it was noted if it was an uphill, , or a downhill,  step. Hikes always start and end at sea level, and each step up or down represents a  unit change in altitude. We define the following terms:

A mountain is a sequence of consecutive steps above sea level, starting with a step up from sea level and ending with a step down to sea level.
A valley is a sequence of consecutive steps below sea level, starting with a step down from sea level and ending with a step up to sea level.
Given the sequence of up and down steps during a hike, find and print the number of valleys walked through.

Example

The hiker first enters a valley  units deep. Then they climb out and up onto a mountain  units high. Finally, the hiker returns to sea level and ends the hike.

Function Description

Complete the countingValleys function in the editor below.

countingValleys has the following parameter(s):

int steps: the number of steps on the hike
string path: a string describing the path
Returns

int: the number of valleys traversed
Input Format

The first line contains an integer , the number of steps in the hike.
The second line contains a single string , of  characters that describe the path.

My solution passes the first 13 tests but fails the last 7 due to timing out.

```
    public static int countingValleys(int steps, string path)
    {
        int valleys = 0;

        int elevation = 0;

        foreach(Char step in path)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(step);

            if (step == 'U')
                elevation++;
            else if (step == 'D')
            {
                elevation--;

                if (elevation == -1)
                    valleys++;
            }
        }

        return valleys;
    }
```

I checked the settings for HackerRank C# environment and the time limit for C# is 3 sections which is plenty. I don't understand why would this take more then 3 seconds?

But how can I optimize the solution if that's possible?

I am also wondering if this is some marketing trick to get me to buy so I can see the hidden tests that are failing and debug it?

Comment: You should check your post, i think numbers may be missing, e.g. "the last hike that took **exactly steps**". Better yet, try to reduce the problem to a simpler one. If you passed 13 tests then your problem might be on a special edge case, e.g. infinite or cyclic problem. Try checking that.

Comment: @JakubFojtik The failing test actually say why it failed. It there was coding error, it would have said `wrong result` but that's not the case. It specifically says it timed out as if the function never return maybe. I just can't see that but will examine more closely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution times out because of the line

```
Console.WriteLine(step);
```

Printing is actually very time consuming and you should get rid of all the debug prints before submitting the final solution.

Comment: Damn, that was it, I missed it.

Answer (score 0):

You never use `int steps`. What if the hike is only 23 steps, but you get a 2 GB string?

Remove

```
foreach(Char step in path)
```

and use

```
for(int i=0 ; i<steps ; i++)
{
    Char step = path[i];
```

instead

Comment: I didn't quite get it why this would be different but tried and same results, still timing out.

Comment: @zar: there is a clear difference if you check 23 steps or 2000000000 steps.